# Drag and Drop events in dnd plugin in jstree do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, tree, jstree

I am using jsTree for tree representation of the Files and folders. I would like move folders from one tree to the other.

For this reason I have enabled the drag and drop plugin (dnd).

Unfortunately it doesn't work if i also use the "types" plugin.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

I am posting the related code below

```
<script>

    function buildTrees() {


        var myTypes = {
            "mg1": {
                "max_depth": 1,
                "valid_children": ["ean"]
            },
            "ean": {
                "max_depth": 0
            },
            "aaa": {
                "max_depth": 2,


                "valid_children": ["mg1"]
            },
            "#": {
                "max_depth": 3,
                "valid_children": ["aaa"]
            }
        };


    }

   var sourceTree = $('#sourceTree').jstree({
            "core": {"check_callback": true}, "plugins": ["search", "wholerow", "dnd",   "checkbox", "types"] , "types": myTypes
        });

        var targetTree = $('#targetTree').jstree({
            "core": {"check_callback": true}, "plugins": ["search", "wholerow", "dnd", "checkbox", "types"] , "types": myTypes
        });



    $().ready(buildTrees());
</script>
```

Comment: Which version are you using? Because since version 3.0beta you need to add seperated files. With version 1 the file is included.

Comment: Thank you Niels.  the version is 3.0 beta. what do you mean that I need 2 different files?

Comment: I have imported these files:    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jstree.com/3.0.0-beta5/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="doubletree.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<script src="http://static.jstree.com/3.0.0-beta5/assets/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.jstree.com/3.0.0-beta5/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.jstree.com/3.0.0-beta5/assets/jquery.address-1.6.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues in jsTree when working with two instances of jsTree in the same doc, and especially when both instances have nodes with same IDs.

Here are the related issues:

https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/1013 - related to node IDs

https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/1014 - related to types plugin

Both issues are **fixed** and closed, thanks to the author!